# Modifying position of AJAX autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I cannot seem to move the autocomplete suggestion despite trying a couple of methods. Here is the code:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url_for("certificates.autoinst") }}'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    $('#institution').autocomplete({
                        source: data.json_list,
                        minLength: 2,
                        position: { my : "center", at: "center", of: "#institution" }
                    });
                });
            });

    </script>

        <input type="text" id="institution"/>
```

The library I am using is: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js

The autocomplete works, but I cannot control the position of the pop-up. I would like the box to be close to the text entry box, say bottom right, but no matter the position I try, the box stays in upper left.

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` at Question ?, create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: and what the position you want it to have?

Comment: @Buzinas, I have updated the question.